Yoga layout in webpack issue
I was updating my dependencies but after updating, when I ran npm install, It did not work else I added --force or ----legacy-peer-deps and so an error occurred after using any of these flags. This is the error that I get:
ERROR in ../../node_modules/yoga-layout/src/generated/YGEnums.ts 10:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| // @generated by enums.py
|

export enum Align {
|   Auto = 0,
|   FlexStart = 1,

webpack compiled with 1 error (05b2b0b974e03a93)
No errors found.
updating dependencies

I had the same issue and resolved it by modifying my Webpack configuration and adding additional extensions:
 resolve: {
   extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".mts", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json"],
 },

I got the solution from this Gitlab Issue.
